# After changing the username,Logout the application from all devices

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-security, mobile-application

In my application user can change their username. If user changed their username means, the particular user account should logout from all devices.
Even in mobile app also.

For this i done following things,

- After changing the username i will delete the **access_token** and **refresh_token** of particular username in server.

  ```
  Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokenCollection = tokenStore.findTokensByUserName(principal.getName());


  for (OAuth2AccessToken oToken : tokenCollection){
      tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oToken);
      tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(oToken.getRefreshToken());
  }
  ```
- If user accessing from mobile app, first i will check the access_token if it is invalid, then i will check with refresh_token. If both is invalid, i will redirect the user to login page. **In mobile app it's working fine**.

But if user logged in through PC means, Following scenario need to handle.

**The Scenario is:**
- After changing the username from mobile App, If user performing any activities in PC, it's giving **"500 Internal Server Error"** or **"XML description of authentication failed"**.

How to handle this?. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Not enough information. Is your application stateless? If it is a normal session-oriented web application, you need to destroy the session.

Comment: My application normal session-oriented web application only. I want to know how to destroy the session?. And Where need to destroy the session(In browser or server side)? Please give the solution.

Comment: session.invalidate(); should be executed on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

consider this...

1. create a database / table with user's status.
2. on changing of username, update the latest user's status in the database.
3. each time the user login, check for user's status from the database / table.
4. then display appropriate messages to user for start a new activities or something like that.